# I see my reverted SVN commit in svn log

Tags: svn

I have reverted my last accidental SVN commit with `svn merge -r COMMITTED:PREV .` It looks like the files are Ok now but I still see that accidental commit in `svn log`.

Is it Ok? Can I remove my last commit from the history?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reverse merge does *not* go back in time and remove all trace of your erroneous commit. 
It simply applies the changes you made in that revision, but in reverse order, to a working copy on your *local machine*.

After the merge you can see the local changes by running `svn status` on your working copy. *Note that nothing has been changed on the SVN server yet.* When you have verified the changes, you can commit them using `svn commit`. This commit will *not* replace your erroneous commit; it is simply another plain-old-vanilla commit<sup>1</sup>. This commit gets its own log message and revision number, which you can verify by running `svn log` after your commit is successful. You will now see both your erroneous commit and the one to fix it.

Is it possible to completely remove the erroneous commit, as if it had never existed? [Technically, yes,](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal) but not with `svn merge` and not without admin rights on the SVN server. In 99.99% of cases, this would be much more effort than it's worth.

Also understand that SVN's history is not really intended to be modified (it is, after all, *history*, and you wouldn't want to become one of those nasty revisionist historians, now would you?). Version control systems like SVN intentionally make it difficult to change history because they are specifically designed to track every change anybody makes to a repo, forever. See [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/105228) to a related question (how to edit previous commit messages) on Programmers SE and the comments for a discussion of *why* changing this history can be bad.

1. *(with the added benefit of automatic merge tracking if you're on a recent version of SVN)*